# Key Press Event

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008, datagridview, keypress

I added a form to a datagridview using the code `datagrid1.controls.add(frmnew)`. The issue is that, key press event of the controls in that form is not firing. Please give me a solution for this.

Comment: Please add correct tags to this question. DataGridView is a .Net control in the System.Windows.Forms namespace. That's not what you're talking about so please remove that tag. Please add tags for the platform and the language. Is this .Net? Web? Are you talking about System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGrid? System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid? Some other language?

Comment: Adding a grid to a form makes sense.  Adding a form to a grid is quite murky, code snippet required.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows forms:

Check in your .Designer.cs file that you have an event handler.

An event handler looks like this:

```
this.datagrid1.KeyPress += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler(this.datagrid1_KeyPress);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture that keypress event inside of the datagridview control, then you must wire up the event *EditingControlShowing*.  Here is an example of capturing the keypress event and only allowing numeric data to be entered into the datagridview cell.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when a control for editing a cell is showing
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>Capture key press to handle key entry in datagridview</remarks>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void dgDCAL_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        dgDCAL.EditingControl.KeyPress -= EditingControl_KeyPress;
        dgDCAL.EditingControl.KeyPress += EditingControl_KeyPress;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handle datagridview cell keypress event
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    void EditingControl_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        // Only allow 0-9, backspace, period and return key
        if (!Char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) && 
            (int)e.KeyChar != 8 &&
            (int)e.KeyChar != 46 &&
            (int)e.KeyChar != 13) e.Handled = true;
    }
```